# User custom page

Tags: wordpress

Hello i created a custom role in wp and i need to list them a show their profiles on the front page. is it possible beacause i cant get url ?

```php
$users = get_users( $args );
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        var_dump($user);
        echo get_the_ID($user);
        echo get_the_permalink( 187,false );
        echo '<li>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '[' . esc_html( $user->user_email ) . ']</li>';
    }
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Where are you expecting to get the URL?  Here? `echo get_the_permalink( 187,false );`

Comment: yep but 187 is id of the page not of the user ... id i put there user it returns false

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't actually understand your question.